# How do I recreate this detuned synth?

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer, replication, electronic-music, waves

I've been looking to recreate this sound from All I Want by Rome In Silver for a long time and I can't figure it out, can anyone help?  It's the detuned chords in the intro and that come in at the second half of the drop.  I'm thinking it's based on saw waves, but I have no idea what gives it that crisp, sharp sound to it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already made a pluck sound in Serum some time ago that is similar to this. To recreate something more like your sound I modified my existing pluck like this:

[image: Serum setup]

When using these waveshapes you might want to experiment a bit with the actual unison and detune parameters to your liking as this was only a quick sketch from the preset I made earlier.

For the LFOs controlling the detune of the two oscillators I suggest to set the timing to free and use seperate LFOs for each oscillator. Each LFO should also have a different frequency, so you end up with this asynchronous detuning effect. You might also think about changing the amount of detune per OSC so they detune differently (like 2 semitones for OSC A and 1 for OSC B).

To create this vinyl/analog sound I added a noise that went well for the effect I tried to achieve and sent it through a lowpass filter. You might adjust the volume of the noise accordingly.

To give the sound some space and give it some additional crispieness and distortion you might want to add some effects like this:
[image: FX chain]

Comment: I can test it later, but damn that skin is dope

Comment: The skin is "Blood" from the "Anthracite" series that can be found here: https://anthracite.aevi.me/

Comment: What is the second LFO in screenshot #1?

Comment: @Jodast It's basically the same as the first LFO but with a slightly different rate so that it creates a non-static detune effect. The exact timing of each LFO may depend a bit on the personal taste. Also the 0.9Hz is only an exemplary value to give an idea of how to design the sound. You could set the second LFO to something like 0.7 or 0.6 Hz for example. But as I said these values are up to you and depend on your own preferences.